# what is si7021 sensor i2c command sequence

Tags: embedded, i2c

From the manual shown bellow the address is 0x40 the measure temperature command 0xE3.

From the readback diagram
first master sends slave address and measure command,then We send slave Adress.

But we cant see in the diagram  where is the measured data,how it transfered back?
The manual doesnt say what is MS Byte,MS Byte.
Thanks. 
https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/Si7021-A20.pdf
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The measured data is contained in the MS Byte and the LS Byte.  The measured data is a two-byte value.  MS Byte is the most significant byte.  LS Byte is the least significant byte.

In the diagram, the unshaded cells represent data transmitted from the master to the slave.
And shaded cells represent data received by the master from the slave.

Comment: Hello in the diagram we see NA and NA* blocks what are they i cant find in the manual their meaning and how they are recognised?
Thanks.

Comment: @rocko445 The "A" block is an acknowledgment (ACK).  The "NA" block is a not-acknowledgement (NACK).  The acknowledgement block is a bit within the transfer.  The device that received the previous byte sends the acknowledge bit.  During the acknowledge bit, the receiver pulls the data line low to acknowledge or high to not-acknowledge.

Comment: The * in "NA*" refers to a note at the bottom of the page.